# parse exception causing app crash

Tags: android, cordova, parse-platform, ionic-framework

My app frequently crashes with message

```
your app unfortunately stopped working
```

I looked at the crash logs and I find the following error in the logs

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 9780): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.RuntimeException: applicationContext is null. You must call Parse.initialize(Context) before using the Parse library.
E/AndroidRuntime( 9780): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: applicationContext is null. You must call Parse.initialize(Context) before using the Parse library.
D/Process ( 9780): com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException:138 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:693 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:69012:26 PM
```

I am building my app in ionic framework and followed pattern present in https://github.com/aaronksaunders/dcww/tree/master/www/js. I am using https://github.com/grrrian/phonegap-parse-plugin [which](https://github.com/grrrian/phonegap-parse-plugin#android) says I need to initialize onCreate. How do I do that, I am assuming my app crash is due to that.

My app.js is

```
angular.module('intuch', ['ionic', 'intuch.controllers'])

  .run(function ($ionicPlatform, ParseService) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      }
      if (window.StatusBar) {
        // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
      }
      ParseService.initialize().then(function () {
        return ParseService.getInstallationId();
      }).then(function (_response) {
        console.log("Parse Initialized " + _response);
        return ParseService.subscribe("broadcast_registered3");
      }).then(function (_response) {
        return ParseService.registerCallback(function (pnObj) {
          alert("in assigned callback " + JSON.stringify(pnObj));
          $state.go('app.dashboard');
        });
      }).then(function (success) {
        console.log("Parse callback registered " + success);
      }, function error(_error) {
        alert(_error);
      });
    });
  })
```

while Parse service is

```
.factory('ParseService', function ($q, $window) {

  var ParseConfiguration = {
    applicationId: "waDzmmDVt7hNmRCoY50wOFN3lsRoW2xu42WrPYLs",
    javascriptKey: "nUROouGGqI4WnbHDlNg5AweSQhmmXD84382xJmuU",
    clientKey: "IF2RHNA0slYDq8feUhweewmcK2uEnOqDnK8J7jUf",
    USING_PARSE: true,
    initialized: false
  };

  return {
    initialize: function () {

      console.log("Missing Parse Plugin " + JSON.stringify($window.parsePlugin));

      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $window.parsePlugin.initialize(ParseConfiguration.applicationId, ParseConfiguration.clientKey, function () {
        console.log("Initialized Parse Plugin");
        deferred.resolve('success');
      }, function (e) {
        deferred.reject(e);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    },

    getInstallationId: function () {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $window.parsePlugin.getInstallationId(function (id) {
        deferred.resolve(id);
      }, function (e) {
        deferred.reject(e);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    },

    subscribe: function (_channel) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $window.parsePlugin.subscribe(_channel, function () {
        deferred.resolve(true);
      }, function (e) {
        deferred.reject(false);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    },

    unsubscribe: function (_channel) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $window.parsePlugin.unsubscribe(_channel, function () {
        deferred.resolve(true);
      }, function (e) {
        deferred.reject(false);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    },

    getSubscriptions: function () {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $window.parsePlugin.getSubscriptions(function (_channelsArray) {
        deferred.resolve(_channelsArray);
      }, function (e) {
        deferred.reject(false);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    },

    registerCallback: function (_pushCallback) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $window.parsePlugin.registerCallback('onNotification', function () {

        $window.onNotification = function (pnObj) {

          _pushCallback && _pushCallback(pnObj);

          alert('We received this push notification: ' + JSON.stringify(pnObj));
          if (pnObj.receivedInForeground === false) {

            // TODO: route the user to the uri in pnObj
          }
        };
        deferred.resolve(true);

      }, function (error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: "You must call Parse.initialize(Context) before using the Parse library." ... Please post your Application  class. I think you don't call Parse.initialize(context) before you use parse

Comment: @CodeMonster added code!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think you missing following :

```
public class YourApplication extends Application{

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Application#onCreate()
 */
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();

    Parse.initialize(this, "YOUR_KEY",
            "YOUR_KEY");

}
}
```

And add it to Manifest.xml

```
 <application
    android:name=".YourApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: I have my androidmanifest.xml file generated automatically during release by cordova and config.xml is the configuration file I create. Can I make android specific changes in config.vml?